# Get Shipping Method after updated_checkout

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

My goal is to show the popup when there is no shipping method available.

I know to use trigger `updated_checkout` but how do I know from that trigger, the shipping method is not available?. so I can trigger to show the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger `update_checkout` using `$( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout',function( data ){});` Try the below code.

```
function check_shipping_method_available(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function( $ ) {
            $( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout',function( data ){
                if( !$('.shipping_method').length ){
                    alert('No Shipping method available');
                    // popup code
                }
            } );
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'check_shipping_method_available', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]